# How do you breakpoint Java code of a React Native app?

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I have a react-native app and I am fine debugging the javascript part of it with my Chrome Dev Tools but I am wondering if it is possible to breakpoint the java code from Android Studio, while running the application with the React Native packager. The way I usually debug native Android application is by running it in debug mode from Android Studio, and that will reinstall the apk on my virtual device/phone. Any idea how I could accomplish the same for my React Native app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do everything you can do similar to debugging native android applications. Open the android folder in your react native project from Android Studio and follow as you would debug android app. You can start the packager separately in a command prompt using the command `"npm start"` from the root directory of your project

Comment: but it looks like when I do debug app in Android studio it tries to install the apk on my phone and stops the packager.

Comment: What version? error? are you seeing. It  seems to be working for me.